# Reading specific value in XML document

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm totally new in XML. I would like to get the value of the database node from my XML document which should be "dbTesting"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MyCompany>
<connections>
  <database>dbTesting</database>
  <server>192.168.0.5</server>
</connections>
</MyCompany>
```

This is what I have at the moment but it's not working:

```vb
  Dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
  doc.Load("XMLFile1.xml")
  MsgBox(doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Database"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way :

```vb
Dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
doc.Load("XMLFile1.xml")
MsgBox(doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//database").InnerXml)
```

`//` in XPath means search for descendant elements.

Comment: Ok it looks like it's case sensitive. I've fixed it now.